# Percentage of open access publication for a given researcher

Tags: research, academia

I am looking for a program, user script, API, or web tool that can indicate, for a given researcher, what percentage of their publication is open access.

Answer (score 1):

A free option would be *ImpactStory*. [Here](https://profiles.impactstory.org/u/0000-0001-6728-7745) is an example of a person with 100% OA articles.

Other than that, commercial databases such as *Web of Science* or *Scopus* contain such data.

This screenshot shows an example of an Author Profile search whereby in the left-handside menu you see the option to refine your search to 'Open Access' publications. One can also download these data as CSV files:

[image: Web of Science search with a menu that allows one to narrow the results down to Open Access publications]

Comment: Franck. did that help you?